# Does Python tuple(set()) maintains order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, tuples

I can't grasp why the program is giving diferent results on diferent times that I run it, thats the real problem. I'm pretty sure the problem is here and not behind on the code, I already run some assertions to check that the input for the code below is the same everytime, I still get diferent results.

The Input comes from a pickle file in disk, once the program is running the results stay the same whem I call the funcion multiple times or open the pickle file multiple times, but if I restart the program the result changes.

I verified that the amount of `True` of the `if tuple(setv) == chave[1]:` changes, Is there any reason for this to happen?. `chave[1]` is a `tuple`. My guess is that `tuple(setv)` can be different coming from the same set because sets don't have order? In Python IDLE tuples from the same simple set are the same. I'm lost.

```
def sorec(dictrecorrencias):
    listarecorrenciaspronta = []
    for chave, valor in dictrecorrencias.items():
        if len(valor) > 1:
            setv = {v[0:3] for v in valor}
            if tuple(setv) == chave[1]:
                listarecorrenciaspronta.append((chave[0], valor))
    return listarecorrenciaspronta
```

Comment: Please post an actual MCVE. And yes, sets don't preserve order, even in python 3.6+, where dictionaries do.

Comment: python 'set' has no order

Comment: While they don't maintain order, in some python versions they'll return a consistent order, while other versions deliberately randomize the order to make sure you don't depend on it.

Comment: python3.7+ will keep dictionary order https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html which you can leverage to define a dictionary of key:None then you get consistent order

Comment: `tuple(setv) == chave[1]` is never guaranteed to work. Just don't do that. `set` objects will maintain a consistent iteration order within a process if the set isn't changed, but if you need to rely on some particular order across invocations, that is definitely not reliable

Comment: @MadPhysicist actual MCVE depends on 4 other functions and the pickle file, I didn't think it was necessary for the question. You can just run this a couple of times: https://github.com/ThiagoLRG/actual-MCVE I tried to make it small.

Comment: @BingWang a dictionary of key:None doesn't behave the same as a set does it?  You want the set values to go into the keys, not the data.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, my suggestion is use the items OP would have put to a set as keys of the dictionary, thereby keeping insertion order. The values of the dict are useless. Now ````(k for k in dictWhichReplacesTheSet)```` will generate the tuple as OP wanted

Comment: Actual MCVE means not showing four other functions, but instead reducing your example to the absolute minimum necessary to describe your problem. A simple inline set initialization with dump and load commands would do it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I reduced it and added a solution very similar to the suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many people have said in the comments, and as you suspected, python `set`s don't always preserve order. There may be some cases when they do, but it might not be a good idea to count on this.

If you want to get the elements from a set in the same order each time, the `sorted()` function is probably a simple solution - it will always return a `list` of the set elements in the same order. [See the python `sorted` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
setv = {v[0:3] for v in valor}
if tuple(sorted(setv)) == chave[1]:
    listarecorrenciaspronta.append((chave[0], valor))
```

You can specify a `key =`  argument to customise the order in which it sorts the data.

Comment: @ThiagoLuiz you should mark the answer as correct if you're satisfied (click the check mark).